# Remove specific class domdocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I have this in dom document:

```
<div><span class="hello"></span><div>
```

And I want to remove all spans with that class. So I tried:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query('//span[@class="hello"]/..');

foreach ($elements as $el) {
  $el->parentNode->removeChild($el);
}
```

But this removes the parent element as well (the div element). How can I **only** remove the span elements?

Comment: The `/..` at the end of your selector is selecting the parent div, not the span

Comment: @iainn Can you please post an answer with working solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **/..** at the end of your XPath selector is selecting the parent element, not the `<span>` itself - `..` means to work one level back up the tree, the same as in a directory path. So in your loop, where you say `parentNode->removeChild`, you're actually removing the div, since `$el` is already the span's parent element.

If you just remove the `/..` from the end of the selector, the code should work as intended.

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query('//span[@class="hello"]');

foreach ($elements as $el) {
    $el->parentNode->removeChild($el);
}
```

Full example: https://3v4l.org/o4dRv